# Random URLs creating flood in website

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, tomcat

Environment: Apache 2.4, Tomcat 7.0.54, Java 7, Ubuntu 14.04.5

We have been noticing a random flood of requests directed at our website.
Flood contains URLs from all parts of the application.
Some URL are invoked via AngularJS 1.x/XHR.

As user is browsing our application, a URL is suddenly seen in access logs for up to 2000 time in span of 2 to 3 minutes.

Both GET and POST URLs are seen in flood report.
The flood stops, most likely, when user clicks on another URL in the page.

All response codes are 200 and browser does not seem to invoke next URL after processing response of previous one.
All requests seems to originate at almost the same time.

We have Akamai, AWS ELB, Apache and tomcat logs and this flood is seen in all access logs, so it must be originating from user's browser.

We suspected that response might be containing a meta refresh tag, but in that case browser would invoke URLs sequentially.
mod_security was enabled when site was running Apache 2.2.2, but such kind meta refresh tag was not seen in response.

Flood seems to originate mostly from user agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" which seems to be Firefox on windows 7, but we have also seen browsers on Windows 10 (i.e. NT 10.0)

Please help if anyone else has seen this kind of flood in their application/website?

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your website.  Unfortunately you have provided no details about it.  I don't see how you think anyone could help you.

Comment: This issue is appearing so randomly and obviously not reproducible by us, hence difficult to provide details. All I can think about providing is access log that shows exactly same URL being processed over and over again with 200 response code, same response size, same user agent etc, and I will have to mask the URL to hide internal details. No errors in catalina.out or Apache error logs.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your website (e.g. HTML/JS content), rather than any of the platform that you've tagged. As @ajb says, without steps to reproduce we can't do anything but be sorry for your experience. Figure out  if the requested URLs are legitimate AJAX-targets - if they are, instrument your JS code with measuring those requests.

Comment: All 2k request bursts are coming from the same client/IP, right? Sounds like an application debugging problem to me.

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock This site is Liferay 6.2 based but I don't have enough evidence to open a support case yet. Flood occurs for non-AJAX URLs also, hence difficult to debug. Recently flood was observed for a page containing document library display portlet. Other times it was observed for a public blog post. We will put debugging code in at least XHR calls and see what we get.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely culprit seems to be this.
https://blogs.oracle.com/ravello/beware-http-requests-automatic-retries

> If an HTTP/1.1 client sends a request which includes a request body,
>   but which does not include an Expect request-header field with the
>   "100-continue" expectation, and if the client is not directly
>   connected to an HTTP/1.1 origin server, and if the client sees the
>   connection close before receiving any status from the server, the
>   client SHOULD retry the request. W3 Hypertext Transfer Protocol --
>   HTTP/1.1